# Get element name from XPath, removing string concatenation

Tags: c#, xpath

Say I have the following XPath

```
var xPath = "/TransactionValues/Entities/Entity/Phones/Phone";
```

Is there a .NET C# class that would allow me to parse this XPath string, and retrieve the last element name ("Phone")?

I tried:

```
var elementName = xPath.Remove(0, xPath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

But if the xPath is like this:

```
var xPath = "/Transactionvalues/Entities/Entity/Phones/Phone/( normalize-space( concat( '(', AreaCode, ')-', First3Phone, '-', Last4Phone ) ) )"
```

I get back `"( normalize-space( concat( '(', AreaCode, ')-', First3Phone, '-', Last4Phone ) ) )"` as the "element name"

The reason I am still trying to get the "Phone" element from this XPath, is because I'm trying to replace the entire "Phone" element, which contains an "AreaCode", "First3Phone", and "Last4Phone" element inside it, which the `( normalize-space...` will concatenate to return a single value that represent's the phone number, when the XPath is used to retrieve the value it represents.

```xml
<Phone>
  <AreaCode></AreaCode>
  <First3Phone></First3Phone>
  <Last4Phone></Last4Phone>
</Phone>
```

I'm trying to replace the entire Phone element, but the only pointer I have to the Phone element has this extra string concat and space normalizing function on the end of it, and I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the "last single node" or whatever you would actually call it in this case.

Comment: It could be as simple as `xPath.Split('/').Last()`, but this would not work for more complicated xpath expressions.

Comment: What do you consider to be the right answer in this last case? Phone? Last4Phone?

Comment: @LarsH In the last case, I'm still trying to get the element name from the provided XPath. In my understanding, that would be `Phone`. I'm not sure what the point of the string concatenation after the last forward slash is, but it doesn't work with the current method we had for getting the element name from an XPath string.

Comment: Zack, it's not clear why you think "the element name" from that XPath should be `Phone`. As such, we could give you an answer that will work for this particular instance, but would have no assurance of working in other XPath expressions. In the XPath expression you showed, the last element name mentioned is `Last4Phone`.

Comment: I've clarified my post a bit further on what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to inject a Phone element in a specific place in the xml, and the only hint I get as to where it belongs is the XPath with the `( normalize-string( concat(...` so I only actually need just up to the Phone element. Is there a built in XPath class or similar that can simply take a XPath string in it's constructor and provide methods for parsing out the element names?

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. I doubt there's a built-in class for parsing an XPath expression, but you could probably use Saxon HE (C# version). I still think the success criteria are not described clearly and generally enough ("whatever you would actually call it in this case") for someone else to be able to craft a solution that we could be confident about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out that the actual issue was that we were missing the `<Phone>...</Phone>` element's inner elements.
The xpath wasn't telling us where to put our new values, it was telling us where it was trying to retrieve them, and when those elements didn't exist, it complained that it couldn't get the value.